# calculated fields: to store in DB or not to store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a ruby on rails application where a user can learn words from a story (having many stories on his list of stories to learn from), and conversely, a story can belong to many users. Although the story is not owned by the user (it's owned by the author), the user can track certain personal things about each story that relate to him and only to him, such as how many words are left to learn in each of his stories (which will obviously differ from user to user).

Currently, I have a has_many :through relationship set up through a third table called users_stories. My concern/question has to do with "calculated fields": is it really necessary to store things like words_learnt_in_this_story (or conversely, words_not_yet_learnt_in_this_story) in the database? It seems to me that things like this could be calculated by simply looking at a list of all the words that the user has already learnt (present on his learnt_words_list), and then simply contrast/compare that master list with the list of words in the story in order to calculate how many words are unlearnt.

The dilemma here is that if this is the case, if all these fields can simply be calculated, then there seems to be no reason to have a separate model. If this is the case, then there should just be a join model in the middle and have it be a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, no? Furthermore, in such a scenario, where do calculated attributes such as words_to_learn get stored? Or maybe they don't need to get stored at all, and rather just get calculated on the fly every time the user loads his homepage?

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated! Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking "is it really necessary to store calculated values in the DB" I answer you. No, it's not necessary.

But it can give you some pros. For example if you have lots of users and the users call those values calculating a lot then it could be more winnable strategy to calculate them once in a while. It will save your server resources.

Your real question now is "What will be more effective for you? Calculate values each time or calculate them once in a while and store in DB?"

Comment: interesting... yes, I definitely will need to call those values a lot in order to display their progress. And every time they open their homepage, they should be able to see a progress bar attached to each story that shows them what they have left to do in each story, so it sounds like a good thing to do would be to attach this calculated value to each user_story entry. Are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: @Michael Downside is that you store in your DB a little more data. But I don't think that tiny extra amount of data would bother you. This downside only affect you when the amount of data to store in DB is huge.

Comment: gotcha, ya, makes sense. So assuming that it does indeed get stored "twice" in different equations, where does the calculating get done? I assume it would go in the appropriate model, no? And that model's code would call some sort of instance variable representing that object's field value in the other model?

Comment: @michaelsking1993 According to the info in your question, it seems natural to me that calculated fields are storing in users_stories table. It's natural again that fields calculating methods are holding by users_stories model. But it really depends on more specific details of your app and it's up to you to decide where to put that logic. However such decisions are out of this topic. Hope our tips would help you.

Answer (score 0):

In a true relational data model you don't need to store anything that can be calculated from the existing data.

If I understand you correctly you just want to have a master word list (table) and just reference those words in a relation. That is exactly how it should be modelled in a relational database and I suggest you stick with it for consistency reason. Just make sure you set the indices right in the database.

If further down the road you run into performance issue (usually you don't) you can solve that problems then by caching/views etc.

Comment: Gotcha. So I guess my main question is, _where_ do I store such calculated values, assuming that they influence the logic of the program? In other words, there is a master list of words the user has learnt, but whether or not certain things are unlocked for him depend on how many words he has learnt in the specific stages. I'm assuming the controller is where this should go, but if this is the case, then what kind of logic goes in the model, if any? (Keeping in mind that many values will be tracked for user progress)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to store calculated values in the DB, but if the values are often used in logic or views its good idea to store it in Database once(calculate again on change) and use from there rather then calculating in views or model.

Comment: Gotcha, from this and VAD's answer, it seems that the way to go is to store it in the DB, even though it's calculated from other fields. However, leifg's answer still has me on the fence. In any case, assuming I stored it in the database, I assume this means that I do the calculations in the appropriate Model file? Or does the calculation happen inside of the controller?

Comment: Models are the best place for your logic and calculations.